# How can i fix this mysql stored function problem?

Tags: mysql

I've been working on mysql database it is a task that i have to do for school. I am trying to find what is the problem with this code. The task is to make function count or return value of all users friends.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `count_friend`(userID int(11)) RETURNS int
BEGIN
declare result INT(11);
SELECT friends INTO result 
FROM users
WHERE friends=userID;
RETURN result;
END
```

I expect to show me the number of friends but it keeps showing me NULL value.
I'm a beginner at programming, currently studying WEB DEVELOPMENT. So, I appreciate if someone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Try `SELECT COUNT(friends) INTO result...`

Comment: @clinomaniac you should add that as an answer and have Stefan mark that as accepted, assuming that does the trick. Newcomers will find it helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count the number of results, use this `COUNT`.

```
SELECT COUNT(friends) INTO result...
```

Comment: Thank you i will try with count function.